Sulphur smell in Hot water only
My system is in this order... Well > Water storage tank > 3 Stage filter > Tankless heater >
My first indication was the dishwasher smelled like I dropped a clove of Garlic in it.
There is no smell in the 3 stage filter, so it has nothing to do with anything before that. I did normal maint. on the water softener and it didn't clear, so I bypassed the water softener, and the smell is still there, ruling the softener out.
I HAVEN'T done a descale / flush of the Tankless heater, which I'm researching... One other thing to note is the Tankless will make a loud moaning sound and shake the floor occasionally, which I think is a cry for maint., but does that tip off anything towards the smell?
Filling up a glass of Hot results in the smell, which goes away in a minute or so. I know it's a gas because of that, but don't understand the WHY...
Thanks for any help.

Some people remove the sacrificial anode, but you could research this as some waters react with the standard type of anode and generate this gas. Maybe replace with zinc-aluminum.

I tend to ask: "Is it hot water, or is it old water?" When the water from the well is in our garden hose for a week or so, it smells very much like sulphide (not sulphur, BTW) when coming out again.

I had the same problem with a regular electric HW tank.  My neighbor did as well. With research I found anaerobic bacteria can grow when the water temp is below 140 deg.
WE both turned the temperature up on the tanks to 140 and the smell went away.
I think your tankless need some maintenance and check the temp.

One of those bacteria is Legionella, which causes Legionnaires' disease and pneumonia. 60C/140F is the recommended temperature to keep your water tank at to prevent that. If that's too hot and you worry about someone burning themselves, install an anti-scalding mixing valve after the heater instead of turning down the tank temperature.

Is that likely in a tankless? At some point, it becomes a question of mass and volume, of which, the tankless lacks.

Okay, the temp has been at 140 for 4 days now, no relief. How long did it take for relief when you did it?

@Mitch, the smell went away after about 3 days.

Ok Thanks. I ordered the pump to descale it, hopefully that helps as well. I would say the smell is about 75% still, but your idea seems to be working, albeit slowly...
